# VBA Insert page break where cell is specified value

Tags: vba, page-break

I need to insert multiple page breaks on a sheet after every cell that is a specified value.  I have a piece of code but currently nothing happens

```
Statement.Activate
Dim c As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String

Set c = Columns("A").Find(What:="Please enter your Client Ref  on the reverse", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = c.Address

Do
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=c.Offset(1)
Set c = Columns("A").FindNext(c)
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
End If
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Comment: Please check the string you inserted in Find: Your code worked for me! (but I searched for "asdf")

Answer (score 0):

Try just looping the rows.

```
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = 1
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    'Loop through and record what is in the first column
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        if ws.Range("A" & lRow) = "Please enter your Client Ref  on the reverse" then
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=c.Offset(1)
        End if

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```

Comment: This gives me a Run Time error 424 'Object Required' on the ActiveWindow.... line?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!  I had printing set to 'All on one page'.